# Wordpress shortcode to upload media (shortcode rendered as tinymce button)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to have a wordpress tinymce button to open media manager, i searched from google but found nothing.
I already have my shortcode and the button embeded on tinymce, it shows a text field to enter some text but i want to add button to open media manager to look for an image.

Anyone have some idea?

Thanks folks

Comment: Check this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-integrate-the-media-library-into-a-plugin

Comment: Hola, thanks so much, will try it